# C++ : Creating a parametrized pointer from a string

Tags: c++, templates

I have a legacy interface that gives me the type to instance under the form of a string, for example "int", "float", etc.

I've came up with these two functions to solve the problem:

```
template <typename T>
T type_factory(const std::string& type_id)
{
    if (!type_id.compare("long"))
    {
        long res;
        return res;
    }

    if (!type_id.compare("double"))
    {
        double res;
        return res;
    }

    if (!type_id.compare("char"))
    {
        char res;
        return res;
    }
}
```

and

```
template <class PointerClass, typename T>
PointerClass<T>* pointer_factory(void* ptr, T dummy_type)
{
    return static_cast<PointerClass<T>*>(ptr);
}

//Desidered usage:
//void* raw_ptr;
//Calculator<int>* p = pointer_factory<Calculator>(raw_ptr, type_factory("int"));
```

The second function doesn't compile the error is "expected unqualified-id" near PointerClass.

Could someone please tell me why the second function does not compile and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first function is not correct. There is no type `T` that is a supertype of `long`, `double` and `char`.

Comment: First of all, don’t use `compare`. Use `==` instead!

Comment: @LucaMartini: You're right. It was a quick hack to poke around with the subject, but if I have to specify the type it's pretty useless though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Could you please tell my why?

Comment: @KonradRudolph `compare` does not create a temporary `std::string`, so I believe in this case it can be better to avoid `operator==`

Comment: @AlfredoDiNapoli Because it’s more readable, and also more natural so the actual question should be: why are you *not* using it? Furthermore, *if* you insist on using `compare`, please don’t rely on interpreting the integer return value as a boolean, that’s also unreadable (C++ shouldn’t allow this conversion anyway). Explicitly compare to an integer value  (i.e. `== 0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need a template template:

```
template < template<typename T> class PointerClass, typename T>
PointerClass<T>* pointer_factory(void* ptr, T dummy_type)
```

instead of

```
template <class PointerClass, typename T>
PointerClass<T>* pointer_factory(void* ptr, T dummy_type)
```

since `PointerClass` is itself a template.

This fixes the compilation error, you'll have to test if it does what you want yourself, though I doubt it will.

EDIT:

Seems like a factory class, instead of templates, might be easier to write and understand by others in this case.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have not finished here but I'm a bit closer to what I want to accomplish :)